# Cypress cancels XMLHttpRequest even though server.ignore returns false

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to test my app with Cypress and on my page, I have a few JS scripts loaded that perform XMLHttpRequests like a NewRelic tracking script for instance. To allow them to run, I wrote this in `cypress/support/index.js` to override `cypress.server()` command. However, my script calls still get canceled by Cypress, I get a Javascript exception and my test fails, what could I be doing wrong here ?

```js
Cypress.Server.defaults({
  // Allow all requests to pass
  ignore: (xhr) => {
    console.log('xhr :>> ', xhr);
    return false;
  },
});
```